# Is there a way to type the elements of the dictionary that is returned by a serializer?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I use the serializers that come from django-rest-framework to validate many of the request on my app end. I have found thhat is very useful to get the objects on the serializer, but the dictionary the serializer returns with the `serializer.validated_data` is not typed

This is how I perform the validation:

On views.py

```
 def post(self, request):
        body_serializer = ExampleSerializer(data=request.data)  
        body_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        body_data = body_serializer.validated_data
        
        # to get the object
        object_one = body_data['object_one']
```

On the serializers.py

```
class ExampleSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    field_one = serializers.CharField(required=True, help_text='field_one')
    field_two = serializers.CharField(required=True, help_text='field_two')
    field_three = serializers.CharField(required=True, help_text='field_three')

    def validate(self, attrs):
        object_one:ObjectOne = ObjectExample.objects.get(field=field_one)
        attrs['object_one'] = object_one

        return attrs
```

Is there a way I can type the return dictionary?

Comment: Why and what actually you want to do is still not understandable.

Comment: @AnuragDhadse I want to be able to set the type of class a dictionary element is, for instance if a set `dictionary["integer_one"] = 777`, I want to be able when I access that key to get the methods the class `int` has. As I said, this is not happening with the returning dictionary in the `validated_data` method coming from the `Serializer` class, for the previous case the type of `dictionary["integer_one"]` will be `any`.

Comment: @AnuragDhadse the reason I want to do this is because I like my code to be typed, so, I'm just wondering if there is a way to accomplish this

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I understand what OP wants: to specify the types of the values for each key in the `validated_data` dict that serializers in DRF return. With PEP489 (TypedDict) this should now be possible, although DRF does not yet use this. I found [some discussion about this topic on DRF's issue tracker](https://github.com/typeddjango/djangorestframework-stubs/issues/36) but it doesn't look like DRF actually ended up implementing this.